# Selecting rows by value in a floating point column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I import a csv data file into a pandas DataFrame `df` with `pd.read_csv`. The text file contains a column with strings like these:

```
y
0.001
0.0003
0.0001
3e-05
1e-05
1e-06
```

If I print the DataFrame, pandas outputs the decimal representation of these values with 6 digits after the comma, and everything looks good.

When I try to select rows by value, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas):

```
df[df['y'] == value],
```

by typing the corresponding decimal representation of value, pandas correctly matches certain values (example: rows 0, 2, 4) but **does not** match others (rows 1, 3, 5). This is of course due to the fact that those rows values do not have a perfect representation in base two.

I was able to workaround this problem is this way:

```
df[abs(df['y']/value-1) <= 0.0001]
```

but it seems somewhat awkward. What I'm wondering is: numpy already has a method, [.isclose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html), that is specifically for this purpose.

Is there a way to use `.isclose` in a case like this? Or a more direct solution in pandas?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use numpy's `isclose`

```
df[np.isclose(df['y'], value)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert values to int, floating point might not equal.
df.loc[df["sum"].astype(int) == int(value)]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).